# JAVA: tweaking SMS character countdown

Tags: java, string, javafx, sms, countdown

I am developing a SMS sending application in JavaFX8.
I need help with tweaking my SMS counter function.

A little background info:

One SMS can contain 160 characters. If you exceed 160 characters, then it becomes multi-part SMS. So the second SMS can contain 146 characters and the third 153 characters. Starting from third SMS every SMS can contain 153 characters.

So it would be like 160 -> 146 -> 153 -> 153 -> 153 ...

Now I want to count down from 160 to 0 and then 146 to 0 and then 153 to 0.

This is what I have so far:

```
smsComposeArea.textProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) -> {
        //Replace all multiple whitspaces with one whitespace
        smsComposeArea.setText(smsComposeArea.getText().replaceAll("[^\\S\\r|\\n|\\r\\n]+", " "));
        //GSM 03.38 Extended charset ^{}\[~]|€ take up 2 characters - count them as 2 chars. Replace multiple tabs, newlines, whitespaces with one.
        int charCount = smsComposeArea.getText().replaceAll("[\\^{}\\\\\\[~\\]|€]{1}", "$0$0").replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|\\r\\n|\\s)+", " ").length();

        int countDown;
        if(smsComposeArea.getText() == null && smsComposeArea.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
            lblCharCounter.setText("160");
        }
        else if(charCount >= 1 && charCount <= 160) {
            countDown = 160 - charCount;
            lblCharCounter.setText(Integer.toString(countDown));
        }
        else if(charCount >= 160 && charCount <= 306) {
            countDown = 146 - (charCount - 160);
            lblCharCounter.setText(String.format("2 SMS %s", Integer.toString(countDown)));
        }
        else if(charCount >= 306 && charCount <= 459) {
            countDown = 153 - (charCount - 306);
            lblCharCounter.setText(String.format("3 SMS %s", Integer.toString(countDown)));
        }
        else if(charCount >= 459 && charCount <= 612) {
            countDown = 153 - (charCount - 459);
            lblCharCounter.setText(String.format("4 SMS %s", Integer.toString(countDown)));
        }
        else if(charCount >= 612 && charCount <= 765) {
            countDown = 153 - (charCount - 612);
            lblCharCounter.setText(String.format("5 SMS %s", Integer.toString(countDown)));
        }
        else if(charCount >= 765 && charCount <= 918) {
            countDown = 153 - (charCount - 765);
            lblCharCounter.setText(String.format("6 SMS %s", Integer.toString(countDown)));
        }
        else if(charCount >= 918 && charCount <= 1071) {
            countDown = 153 - (charCount - 918);
            lblCharCounter.setText(String.format("7 SMS %s", Integer.toString(countDown)));
        }
        else if(charCount >= 1071 && charCount <= 1224) {
            countDown = 153 - (charCount - 1071);
            lblCharCounter.setText(String.format("8 SMS %s", Integer.toString(countDown)));
        }
        else if(charCount >= 1224 && charCount <= 1377) {
            countDown = 153 - (charCount - 1224);
            lblCharCounter.setText(String.format("9 SMS %s", Integer.toString(countDown)));
        }
        else if(charCount >= 1377 && charCount <= 1530) {
            countDown = 153 - (charCount - 1377);
            lblCharCounter.setText(String.format("10 SMS %s", Integer.toString(countDown)));
        }


    }
);
```

It works as it is supposed to, but I think there should be more sophisticated or dynamic way to display the countdown. Too many IF-statements in my opinion.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is that supposed to be GSM? Because if so, it's either one message of 160 *bytes*, or every single message part including the first becomes 154 *bytes* because they all have an equal-length 6-byte UDH. Or 153 for an extended ID UDH.

Comment: I took an example of how sms length is calculated from here:
https://dashboard.messente.com/sms/calculator

Comment: And also this: http://messente.com/blog/2012/09/15/how-is-length-of-the-sms-calculated/

Comment: Well, they are saying the same thing as I just did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you work with an 8-bit SMS encoding, where each character takes one byte, what happens is this:

- If the length of the message is up to (and including) 160 characters, you have one message. Your remaining characters are 160 - n, where n is the number of characters typed.
- If the length of the message exceeds 160 characters (161 and above), then, given an extended UDH of 7 bytes, each segment has a length of 153 characters. This means ⌈n/153⌉ segments. And the number of characters until the end of the current segment is ⌈n/153⌉×153-n.

Which means that you are not supposed to have many "if" statements at all:

```
if ( charCount <= 160 ) {
    nSegments = 1;
    countDown = 160 - charCount;
} else if ( charCount % 153 == 0 ) {
    nSegments = charCount / 153;
    countDown = 0;
} else {
    nSegments = charCount / 153 + 1;
    countDown = nSegments * 153 - charCount;
}
lblCharCounter.setText(String.format("%d SMS %d", nSegments, countDown) );
```

Answer (score 1):

There is free SMS length calculation library available at https://github.com/messente/sms-length-calculator which detects encoding and also takes care of trailing escape characters for extended gsm 7bit charset in the multipart SMS.

You can also learn and experiment with online sms length calculator at http://messente.com/documentation/sms-length-calculator

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about SMS protocols, but assuming your background information is correct you can do:

```
IntegerBinding textLength = Bindings.length(smsComposeArea.textProperty());

IntegerBinding numberOfSms = Bindings.createIntegerBinding(() -> {
    if (textLength.get() <= 160) {
        return 1 ;
    } else if (textLength.get() <= 306) {
        return 2 ;
    } else {
        return 3 + (textLength.get() - 307) / 153 ;
    }
}, textLength);

IntegerBinding remainingChars = Bindings.createIntegerBinding(() -> {
    if (numberOfSms.get() == 1) {
        return 160 - textLength.get() ;
    } else if (numberOfSms.get() == 2) {
        return 306 - textLength.get() ;
    } else {
        return 306 + (numberOfSms.get() - 2) * 153 - textLength.get() ;
    }
}, numberOfSms, textLength);

lblCharCounter.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("%d SMS %d", numberOfSms, remainingChars));
```

If the computation in @RealSkeptic's answer is correct, then you can do

```
IntegerBinding textLength = Bindings.length(smsComposeArea.textProperty());

IntegerBinding numberOfSms = Bindings.createIntegerBinding(() -> {
    if (textLength.get() <= 160) {
        return 1 ;
    } else {
        return 1 + (textLength.get() - 1) / 153 ;
    }
}, textLength);

IntegerBinding remainingChars = Bindings.createIntegerBinding(() -> {
    if (numberOfSms.get() == 1) {
        return 160 - textLength.get() ;
    } else {
        return numberOfSms.get() * 153 - textLength.get() ;
    }
}, numberOfSms, textLength);

lblCharCounter.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("%d SMS %d", numberOfSms, remainingChars));
```

or perhaps (with a grand total of zero `if` statements)

```
IntegerBinding textLength = Bindings.length(smsComposeArea.textProperty());

BooleanBinding singleSMS = textLength.lessThanOrEqualTo(160);

IntegerBinding numberOfSms = Bindings.when(singleSMS).then(1).otherwise(
    textLength.subtract(1).divide(153).add(1));
IntegerBinding remainingChars = Bindings.when(singleSMS).then(textLength.subtract(160).multiply(-1)).otherwise(
    numberOfSms.multiply(153).subtract(textLength));

lblCharCounter.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("%d SMS %d", numberOfSms, remainingChars));
```

depending on the style you prefer.

Comment: Thank you for thinking along! This code works very well!